# Not able to click on the Button in android AVD

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am very much new to Appium Automation 
I am Using appium 1.13.0
Android Os : Nougat 7.0
I am running the code on Eclips have created the AVD

I have Used

```
FindElementBy.xpath("//[@class=‘android.widget.Button’ and 
@index=‘2’]").click(),
className(“android.widget.Button”)
xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(contains(@text,‘LOGIN’))]")
xpath("//[contains(@class, ‘android.widget.Button’)][contains(text(),‘LOGIN’)]");
```

Nothing works for me

```
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {“cmd”:“action”,“action”:“find”,“params”:{“strategy”:“xpath”,“selector”:"//*[@class=‘android.widget.Button’ and @index=‘2’]",“context”:"",“multiple”:false}}

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {“cmd”:“action”,“action”:“find”,“params”:{“strategy”:“xpath”,“selector”:"//*[@class=‘android.widget.Button’ and @index=‘2’]",“context”:"",“multiple”:false}}

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding ‘//*[@class=‘android.widget.Button’ and @index=‘2’]’ using ‘XPATH’ with the contextId: ‘’ multiple: false
```

Comment: Is the app open in the right screen? Are you sure the layout contains the element you're looking for?

Comment: @MarcSances yes it is open and element is available on the UI
[https://imgur.com/SkpxMPH]

Comment: Double-check with the Appium Desktop inspector if you can, or get a print of the layout and find the element there: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/source/ . Appium reconstructs the layout based on what UIAutomator provides it and sometimes it misses objects and makes a mess. The object should be visible in the screen at the time you ask to click it, by the way.

Comment: @MarcSances  whenever I am Starting the Appium Desktop inspector and start the session it just loading but nothing showing on the appSource .. Is there any other way to start the session

Comment: Did you set the `appPackage` and `appWaitActivity` capabilities? Are those correct? Appium will wait until the specified activity is loaded before actually starting the tests.

Comment: @MarcSances yes both are correct my app is opening on AVD

Comment: If you're using UiAutomator try switching to UiAutomator2 to see if it makes a change `automationName: UiAutomator2`. UiAutomator has given us enough trouble lately.

Comment: @MarcSances when i use this I am getting 
`An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command ''C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_162\\bin\\java.exe' -jar 'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\sign.jar' 'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' --override' exited with code 1`

Comment: @MarcSances how do i get appWaitActivity and what is the use of this

Comment: @MarcSances have you go any solution for this as I am stuck in between and I am not bale to find any solution for this Sorry to bother you

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see any more troubleshooting tips to give you. I know for real how frustrating it can be to work with this framework. Sorry :/

Comment: @MarcSances  I have got solutions I have unistalled the appium and installed once again and it started working thanks for your help